Jetpack compose: how to use endless pager?
I'm using HorizontalPager from compose.foundation. I need to make endless pager, here my code:
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (useEndlessPager) {
            val halfMax = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2
            val remainder = halfMax % pageCount
            val initPage = if (remainder == 0) halfMax else halfMax + pageCount - remainder

            val pageSettled = state.initialPage in (halfMax - pageCount)..(halfMax + pageCount)
            if (!pageSettled) {
                state.scrollToPage(initPage + state.initialPage)
            }
        }
    }

The problem is that starting with version 1.6.8, the state.initialPage became unavailable:

Unresolved reference: initialPage

And I don't understand how to make an endless pager in this case. Please help me.

initialPage  page is put back on but using Int.MAX_VALUE as pageCount started causing ANR with 1.6. You need to use smaller numbers now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75469260/5457853
